# $ionicHistory is not keeping track of views with parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am having an issue with ionic framework app. When user moves from one view to another, to get him back on previous view I am using following code.

```
$ionicHistory.goBack();
```

It is working fine with the view without parameters. But failing to go back on the views with query string parameters.

I think views with parameters not getting added in history.
Can anyone help me how to add these views in history?

Comment: can you specify more what you mena with "views with query string parameters"? can you make an example or drop a codepen?